# How does webservice maintain session when client is windows/Console app?

Tags: c#, web-services

How does webservice maintain session when client is windows/Console app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using cookies.

When you send HTTP requests, make sure to include a `CookieContainer`.  (assuming you're using `HttpWebRequest`)

Comment: Can you give me some example how to use CookiContainer?

Comment: @santosh: `request.CookieContainer = someContainer`.  `someContainer` should be a `CookieContainer` instance shared by all requests.

Comment: Do you have any example that use  CookiContainer?

Comment: @santosh: What are you having trouble with? Did you check the documentation?

Answer (score 2):

Under the covers, the C# WebClient is storing the cookie given to it by the web service.

Answer (score 0):

Here is some sample code if someone is interested.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        CookieContainer session = new CookieContainer();

        HttpWebRequest httpSomeRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://localhost:8080/someURL");
        httpSomeRequest.CookieContainer = session;
        httpSomeRequest.GetResponse();

        HttpWebRequest httpSomeOtherRequest  = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://localhost:8080/someOtherURL");
        httpSomeOtherRequest.CookieContainer = session;
        httpSomeOtherRequest.GetResponse();
    }
}
```

We just need to make sure that every `HttpWebRequest` made, uses the same `CookieContainer` instance.